# Offline StreetMap implementing using OSMDroid

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am trying to implement offline StreetMap using OSMDroid.

I am confused about how to implement it: How can we provide tiles to maps from zip files?

I read many tutorials but I don't understand how it can be done. I get zip files of tiles using Mobile Atlas Creator.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can make the map works offline. Here are the steps:

1. Using MOBAC to create offline map (either Mbtiles or sqlite works for me) and copy it to your phone's sdcard  `/sdcard/osmdroid/`
2. Create a custom tile source for your map source which you use in MOBAC to create your map as:`private final XYTileSource FourUMapsTileSource = new XYTileSource("4uMaps", 0, 18, 256, ".png", new String[ {"http://tileserver.4umaps.eu/"});` (here I used 4uMaps as my tile source)
3. Change `mapview` setting: `mapView.setUseDataConnection(false);`, `mapView.setTileSource(FourUMapsTileSource);`

You can look at this [Guide](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Offline-Map-Tiles) for more detail.

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank You for these steps , I have already follow these but doesn't get offLine Map..